# overflow issues with content/webparts

Tags: 2013, web-part, css, master-page

I have an issue with overflow in the s4-workspace container (see picture).  Ideally, I'd like the parent div that the content is placed in to stretch EQUALLY with the content.  Instead, I get this gap between my footer and the topNav.

[image]

The current set up i have goes like this:

```
<div id="s4-workspace">
   <div id="container">
      <header id="topNav"></header>
      <div id="main">
         <div id="quicklaunch"></div>
         <div id="content">ALL USER CONTENT HERE</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

All divs are set to a width of 100% including the body.  Overflow for the s4-workspace ID is set to visible.   I've set the main div to display as flex, and the quicklaunch div has a width of about 18%, and the content div has a width of 82%.